# Plotting multiple curves in R with different number of observations in the same interval

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot several curves, say C1, C2 and C3 in R where the *limits* of the x-axis values of the data points are all in the [0,1] interval. But the number of values within this interval differs. What I have is the probability of a certain event occurring at different points of time within a time-interval. The data is of the type

```
C1 occurs with probability 0.55 at time 0.05
                           0.12 at time 0.25
                           0.33 at time 0.80

C2 occurs with probability 0.20 at time 0.45
                           0.80 at time 0.55

C3 occurs with probability 0.15 at time 0.50
                           0.85 at time 0.90
```

I have worked a little on plotting graphs with R before, but I've always encountered data where the number of observations is the same. I am at a loss about how to plot this kind of data. Any help (links, pointers) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a `ggplot` solution? Use `geom_line` if you just want lines; I like `geom_area` better for this case. It may be misleading though, so make sure the selected geom suits your purposes.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(type = c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3"), 
                 prob = c(0.55, 0.12, 0.33, 0.2, 0.8, 0.15, 0.85), 
                 time = c(0.05, 0.25, 0.8, 0.45, 0.55, 0.5, 0.9))
ggplot(df, aes(x=time, y=prob, colour=type, fill=type)) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.5) + 
  ylim(c(0, 1)) + 
  xlim(c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(0, type='n', xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1)) # empty plot with limits set to 0-1 in both dimensions
lines(c(0.05,0.25,0.8), c(0.55, 0.12, 0.33), col='red') # line C1
lines(c(0.45,0.55), c(0.2, 0.8), col='blue') # line C2
lines(c(0.5,0.9), c(0.15, 0.85), col='green') # line C3
legend('topleft', legend=c('C1', 'C2', 'C3'), col=c('red', 'blue', 'green'), lty=c(1,1,1)) #legend
```

This does not look nice, however. Perhaps you should also set values at time 0 and 1.